# Error on result page

Tags: sql-server

I am new learning MS SQL Server. When ever i click on Execute or Cntrl F5, instead of displaying result, it is giving me errors. This is a screenshot of a query i just typed. Kindly tell me the cause of the problem, or what am i doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to run the entire script (including the `create table` at the top).  Apparently, you have already run that part of the script (or that table already exists in general).

Before running the entire script again, issue `drop table employees`.

If you're on at least SQL Server 2016, you can use `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employees` at the very top of the script.

If you are running a version of SQL Server that is earlier than 2016, you could put something like this at the very top of the script

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.employees', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.employees;
```

Comment: i appreciate this. I just dropped the table and the result showed. Thanks a million

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to run the select query you should highlight it before running the query.

When some text is highlighted  clicking execute or hitting F5 will only run the highlighted text.

As you haven't selected your query in your screenshot you are running everything and you are running into the issue Scott explained in his answer.